# angular cli 1.0.0-beta-19 add 3rd Party Library not shown in dist

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Mac OSX El Capitan

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
node: 6.3.1
os: darwin x64
```

I tried to add a ng2-select folder to dist but after I build it doesn't add to the dist folder. Additionally, I don't have all the component folders and services.
In the dist folder I have only this file:

I don't have an error message in the app.

I used a previous version of Angular cli and I was working with systemJs.
I do not understand the new version upgrade and how to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any library to the `dist/` directory manually. It has to be handled by `webpack`.

The official GitHub has a guide for handling of [3rd party libraries](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation). In case of `ng2-select` library it should be enough just to install it via `npm ng2-select --save` and import & use it in your code.